# Create a button with a down arrow icon

Tags: c, winapi, button

I want to create a button with a down arrow icon that displays a menu when clicked. I have found the following button type:

[image]

But this button can be pressed in two places (on the left of the vertical line and on the right of the vertical line), also I don't want the button to have a vertical line, I want it to be something like this:

[image]

Can this be done in Windows API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done using either:

1. a standard [COMBOBOX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/combo-boxes) with the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` window style:

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC510543.png))</sub>

2. A [Menu button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-command-buttons):

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725208.png))</sub>

However, this is not a standard Win32 control.  MFC has a [CMFCMenuButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubutton-class?view=msvc-170) class for it, but in Win32 you have to owner-draw a standard [BUTTON control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) to achieve the same effect:

[Menu button arrow with raw Win32](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216133414/http://poiru.net/2012/06/17/win32-menu-button)

When the button is pushed, you can display your pop-up menu as needed, using [`TrackPopupMenu()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu) or equivalent.

Comment: I believe, the OP really wants a [menu button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742402.aspx#usage), that initiates an operation. A combobox is more appropriate for selecting an option.

Comment: @IInspectable This is exactly what I want. But how can I create such a button, should I just set the button's text to the down arrow character?